# Is $S$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

let  $S =  \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :  x\notin \mathbb{Z} , y \notin \mathbb{Z} \}$ . Is  $S$ is  open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

My attempt : yes , i was thinking  about the  theorem that  complements  of closed set is  open

Is its  true  ?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus S$ is composed entirely of isolated points, so it is closed.

Comment: @David Kraemer the point $(2,\frac{1}{2})$ is not isolated. You can build a sequence in $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus S$ which converges to it.

Comment: @Mark, Is not $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus S = \mathbb{Z}^2$?

Comment: @DavidKraemer no, it's a sum of parallel lines (to either of axis) passing trough integer values on $x$ or $y$ axis.

Comment: @Mark I think there is a problem of interpretation. Is $S$ the set of points $(x,y)$ such that $x$ *and* $y$ are not integers, or $x$ *or* $y$ is not an integer?

Comment: @Mark, my mistake! Bamboozled by De Morgan yet again.

Comment: @Ruben Well, usually $x\notin\mathbb{Z},y\notin\mathbb{Z}$ means that both are not in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Mark It's impressive how confusing a simple statement can be sometimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a cute way: Consider the continuous function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y)=\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)$. Then $f(x,y)\neq0$ if and only if $\sin(\pi x)\neq0$ and $\sin(\pi y)\neq0$ which occurs if and only if $(x,y)\in S$. Since $f$ is continuous, the set of points $(x,y)$ where $f(x,y)\neq0$ is open. Thus, $S$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

$$S = \bigcup_{i, j\in Z} A(i, j),\ A(i, j) = \{(x, y): i<x<i+1,  j<y<j+1\} $$
It sufficies to prove that $A(i, j)$ are open, but it's trivial since Chebyshev and Euclidean metrics are equivalent, and $A(i, j)$ is a ball in Chebyshev metric with center $(i+1/2, j+1/2)$ and radius $1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

The functions $f(x,y)=x, g(x,y)=y$ are both continuous maps from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R.$ Observe that $\mathbb Z$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R,$ which implies $\mathbb R\setminus Z$ is open in $\mathbb R.$ By continuity, both $f^{-1}(\mathbb R\setminus Z),g^{-1}(\mathbb R\setminus Z) $ are open. Hence so is their intersection, which is exactly the set $S.$

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly find an open ball disjoint from $\Bbb R^2\setminus S$, centered at any $(x,y)\in S$.  Just let $r=\operatorname {min}(d(x,\Bbb Z), d(y,\Bbb Z))$.  Then $B_{(x,y)}(r)$ is such a ball.